Thermodynamics of Direct Air Capture of ${\rm CO_2}$: estimating the minimal energy requirements with the Gibbs Free Energy of Mixing
Recently I've watched a great video from a YouTube channel called "Cool Worlds" titled How Thermodynamics Hold Negative Carbon Tech. In that video, Professor David Kipping talks about how challenging it is to design systems of Direct Air Capture of ${\rm CO_2}$ due to their high energy requirements. I don't dispute that. Actually, I think Dr. Kipping might have grossly underestimated how energy intensive that process could actually be, and that is what my question is about (since the video is a few months old, I don't have much hope that my comments in the video will get answered, so I hope I can get help from Stack Exchange)
At 9:29, Dr Kipping explains the Thermodynamic fundamentals of the problem of removing ${\rm CO_2}$ from air. According to him, the absolute minimum energy that would be required to accomplish that challenge is given by the Gibbs Free Energy of mixture of the solution air-${\rm CO_2}$:
$$E = \Delta G = RT \log\left(\frac{p_1}{p_0}\right)$$
Where $p_1$ is the partial pressure of CO2 (400 ppm = 400E-06 atm), $p_0$ is the atmospheric pressure (1 atm) and T is room temperature (300 K). Using R = 8.31 J/molK, he calculated E = 19.5 kJ/mol.
My objection is that previously in the same video (starting at 7:50) he states that the DAC works by passing the air through either a solid or liquid sorbent material that captures the ${\rm CO_2}$. In order to regenerate the sorbent, it is needed to heat it to around 100 °C in case of solids and a whopping 900 °C in the case of liquids. Not only is that hardly room temperature, but also the temperature is variable, since we need to heat air by ~75 °C in the case of solid sorbents.
So, is the Gibbs Free Energy of mixing even the appropriate thermodynamic potential to estimate the bare minimum energy required to opperate a DAC? Isn't the Gibbs Free Energy more appropriate for isothermal and isobaric systems? Why not using the Enthalpy of mixing instead? Am I missing something?

For an ideal gas mixture, the enthalpy of mixing is zero.

The presenter states a minimum energy to get the CO2 out of the air, and you object that they have not added in other parts of the process. The minimum is still the minimum.

@JonCuster that is technically correct, albeit my point is that 19.5 kJ/mol underestimates the actual minimum by a lot. At that point, why not say that the minimum energy requirement is zero and call it a day?
